# When looping through an array of objects, how do I push object values into a new array?

Tags: javascript

Suppose you have the following array:

```
const arr = [
  {'stars': 5},
  {'stars': 4},
  {'stars':5}
]
```

How would one go about extracting all the integers from the 'stars' keys, and pushing them into an array?

I've tried the following

```
arr.map(item => {
  let arr = []
  arr.push(...arr,item.stars)
  console.log(arr)
})
```

...but it just pushes each number into it's own array, as follows:

```
[5] [4] [5]
```

What is I want is an array that looks like this:  `[5,4,5]`

Suggestions?

Comment: You can use map to make a new array with the values you want

Answer (score 0):

You should return the result you want for each element.

Then, you assign the result of `map` to some new array.

```
const arr = [
  {'stars': 5},
  {'stars': 4},
  {'stars': 5}
];
const res = arr.map(item => {
  return item.stars;
});
console.log(res);
// [ 5, 4, 5 ]
```

See also the docs for [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Array#map`

```js
const arr = [
  {'stars': 5},
  {'stars': 4},
  {'stars':5}
]

const newArr = arr.map(a=>a.stars)

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop the array of object to create a new array, you could do like this

```
const arr = [
  {'stars': 5},
  {'stars': 4},
  {'stars':5}
]

let newArr = [];

for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   newArr.push(arr[i].stars);
}

console.log(newArr); // [5,4,5]
```